# ng-style background color not working

Tags: angularjs

Hi friends i'm beginner for angularjs.i'm stuck how to show background color to ng-style from controller

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.color = 'yellow';
  $scope.zoom = 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-style="{'background-color': color }">
</div>
```

Comment: Your example is working as expect, but to see the effect on view you have to Add some content in a `div` or specify `height` & `width` do `div`. [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7GWIOakMN4coMAXuUg6m?p=preview)

Comment: Jeeez, this comment saved me.. i forgot to set dimensions to div >.<

Answer (score -1):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.color = 'yellow';
  $scope.zoom = 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-style="{'background-color': color }">
welcome
</div>
```